# To get date when column value changes from no to yes in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has ID,Date,Flag indicator (which includes yes or no value)
I want to get latest date when flag indicator changed from No to Yes which determines as of today if that ID is in scope or not..

```
ID  Date    Flag Indicator
1   2-Jan-15    No
1   4-Jan-16    Yes
1   2-Jan-17    No
1   1-Jan-18    Yes
```

for the above result must be 1 Jan 2018
but for below

ID Date    Flag Indicator
    2   2-Jan-15    No
    2   4-Jan-16    Yes
    2   2-Jan-17    No
    2   1-Jan-18    No

```
Result must be null
```

because based on latest date Flag Indicator is 'No' which mean its not in scope.

ID Date    Flag Indicator
    4   2-Jan-15    No
    4   4-Jan-16    Yes
    4   2-Jan-17    Yes
    4   1-Jan-18    Yes

Result be 4 Jan 2016 because this was the date when indicator came in scope with Yes

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please share with us the code you tried already, and tell us what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that uses window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when flag = 'Yes' and prev_flag = 'No' and
                  running_no = max(partition by id running_no) over ()
             then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as new_flag
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when flag = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by date) as running_no,
             lag(flag) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_flag
      from t
     ) t;
```

Window functions are generally going to perform better than solutions using correlated subqueries, self-joins, or `apply`.

If you just want one row for each id, then I think of using correlated subqueries:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
where t.flag = 'yes' and
      t.date > (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.flag = 'no') 
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by date);
```

Comment: your second query is a good one, I have optimized it a bit.. take a look

Answer (score 0):

Check the maximum No date, then retrieve the minimum Yes date after that one.

```
;WITH MaxNoDateByID AS
(
    SELECT
        N.ID,
        MaxNoDate = MAX(N.Date)
    FROM
        NumberedDates AS N
    WHERE
        N.Flag = 'No'
    GROUP BY
        N.ID
)
SELECT
    T.ID,
    MinYesDateAfterNo = MIN(T.Date)
FROM
    YourTable AS T
    INNER JOIN MaxNoDateByID AS M ON T.ID = M.ID
WHERE
    T.Date > M.MaxNoDate -- Assuming all dates after MaxNoDate are supposed to be Flag Yes
GROUP BY
    T.ID
```

Comment: I am looking for immediate date when record got changed from no to yes...edited first example ...please help

Comment: @Dav1 edited, please check if it solves your problem now :)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[flagindicator](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL,
    [flagindicator] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[flagindicator] ([id], [date], [flagindicator]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x6F390B00 AS Date), N'No')
INSERT [dbo].[flagindicator] ([id], [date], [flagindicator]) VALUES (1, CAST(0xDE3A0B00 AS Date), N'Yes')
INSERT [dbo].[flagindicator] ([id], [date], [flagindicator]) VALUES (1, CAST(0x4A3C0B00 AS Date), N'No')
INSERT [dbo].[flagindicator] ([id], [date], [flagindicator]) VALUES (1, CAST(0xB63D0B00 AS Date), N'Yes')
INSERT [dbo].[flagindicator] ([id], [date], [flagindicator]) VALUES (2, CAST(0xB63D0B00 AS Date), N'Yes')
INSERT [dbo].[flagindicator] ([id], [date], [flagindicator]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x4A3C0B00 AS Date), N'No')
INSERT [dbo].[flagindicator] ([id], [date], [flagindicator]) VALUES (2, CAST(0xDE3A0B00 AS Date), N'Yes')
INSERT [dbo].[flagindicator] ([id], [date], [flagindicator]) VALUES (2, CAST(0x6F390B00 AS Date), N'No')


SELECT id,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN flagindicator='Yes' THEN date END ),'') indicator FROM flagindicator GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *subquery* with correlation

```
select * from table t
where Date = (select max(Date) from table where id = t.id) and 
     [Flag Indicator] = 'Yes'
```

**EDIT :**

Use `INNER JOIN` as self join containing max_date for each id with *correlation* approach

```
select 
       top (1) with ties t.Id, 
              (case when (select top 1 [Flag Indicator] from table
                             where id = c.id and date = c.MAXDATE) <> 'No' 
                    then date end) as Date
from table t inner join (
        select id, max(date) MAXDATE from table group by id
) c on c.id = t.id
order by row_number() over(partition by t.Id 
                               order by case when [Flag Indicator] = 'Yes' 
                                             then 0 else 1 end)
```

Check [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b372/1)

Comment: what about `ID =2`?

Comment: doesn't work if there are more than one changes in flag: no->yes->no->yes

Comment: @MtwStark.. check with demo.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1**
I have corrected the output date to the first and not the last good.
**EDIT 2**
Added protection against same id/date.
Added optimized version.

I'm assuming your `[Date]` column is a `DATETIME`, in this way you will find your desired output:

```
DECLARE @YourDesiredID INT = 1;

;WITH
t1 as (select distinct ID from YourTable),
m1 as (
    select *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by id, t.date, flag) desc) n, 
        LAG (flag, 1, 'No ') OVER (partition by id order by id, t.date, flag desc) ) PrevFlag
    from YourTable t
),
t2 as (select * from m1 where n=1 and flag = 'Yes'),
m2 as (
    select id, max(m1.date) [date]
    from m1     
    where flag = 'Yes' and PrevFlag = 'No ' 
    group by id
)
select 
    --t1.id, 
    m2.date
from t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
left join m2 on m2.id = t2.id
where t.ID = @YourDesiredID
```

An optimized version could use `MAX([Date])` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` but you must be sure you cannot have more records with the same id/date.
These are the optimized subqueries:

```
t1 as (select ID, max(date) maxdate from t group by id),
m1 as (select *, LAG (flag, 1, 'No') OVER (partition by id order by id, t.date, flag desc) PrevFlag from t),
t2 as (select m1.* from m1 join t1 on t1.id = m1.id where maxdate = date and flag = 'Yes'),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to acomplish this task, I think this is an optimization of @GordonLinoff answer, this is simpler and more performant.

```
select t.id, min(date) date
from YourTable
left join (
    select id, max(date) maxdate_no
    from YourTable
    where flag = 'no'
    group by id
) tn on tn.ID = t.ID
where t.flag = 'yes' and t.date > tn.maxdate_no
group by t.id
```